# Plotting NIntegrate result obtined from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to get a plot of x vs dpdx when - 0.5 < x < 0.5  which uses the results of NDsolve and F vs delp when -2<F<2.

```
 sol[x_] := Module[{a, b, t, Q0, alp, alpha, m, beta, k, F, h, sol},
       a = 0.5;
       b = 2.0;
       t = 0.0;
       Q0 = 1.0;
       alp = 0.5;
       alpha = 0.5;
       beta = 1.0;
       k = 0.5;
       m = 50;
       F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
       h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
       sol = NDSolve[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
          p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0, 
          s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, {s, 
          p}, {y, 0, h}];
       dpdx = p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y]);
       delp = NIntegrate[Evaluate[dpdx /. sol], {x, 0, 1}];
       {0, h, sol}];
    Monitor[data = Flatten[Table[{0, h, funcs} = sol[x];
         Table[{x, y, Last@(p[y] /. funcs)}, {y, 0, h, .005}], {x, 0, 
          1, .005}], 1];, {x, y}]
```

Comment: The dummy variable in `NIntegrate[Evaluate[dpdx /. sol], {x, 0, 1}]`should be y not x.

Comment: Is it possible to get a plot of dpdx vs x?

Comment: Correct your code, without a running code it is hard to advice.